# Change search Google in Safari to use Firefox

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari, firefox

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> searches for the selected text in Google using Safari. Can I change this to use Firefox instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a new service with automator, use the "Run Shell Script" action, and use:

`open -a FireFox "http://www.google.com/search?q=$1"`

as the shell script text, then save it as "Open with Firefox" or whatever you like.

-or-

follow this summary from [this thread](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?p=584323):

1. Download and Install OnMyCommand/OMCEdit
2. Open OMCEdit
3. Click on "Download Commands" then "Download"
4. Go in "Command Library"
5. Choose #22 and click on "Append to Command"
6. Change the name if you want (in "Command Name")
7. Write " Top Level " in location if you don't want a sub-menu, or choose a name for the sub-menu ("In On My Command" is the default)
8. Save
9. You're done!

Comment: For the Automator method, I just had to ensure I had the input passed as arguments

Comment: ya that screwed me up for a minute as well.. I was coming back to edit with that caveat ;P

Comment: Actually, that only works if I select a single word, not a couple of words

Comment: @Casebash my bad, move the end quotes to outside of the variable $1... updated post

Comment: I wish there was a way to edit the default services, but I haven't been able to find anything other than statements about how they're "built into the operating system".

Comment: @calavera - the way to get a new service isn't to change an existing service, but to add your own instead (as described in my answer—no extra apps required).

Comment: @Dori That's actually what I was describing in the first line of my post, creating an Automator action and saving as a service.  I did it when I wrote his answer but I guess I forgot to put the part about it being a service rather than a workflow.  In my comment I was actually just lamenting that you can't just edit the default "Search With Google" action rather than creating a new one.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is create a new Automator service. Unfortunately, Firefox's AppleScript support sucks, so you'll have to do it manually.

You should be able to use a combination of the tips in [this article](http://olifante.blogs.com/covil/2008/08/using-automator-to-move-all-opera-tabs-to-firefox.html) and [this comment](http://www.atpm.com/12.07/automator.shtml#25561), and the page Calavera linked to should give you a general idea of how to format the URLs.