# Custom shortcut executes service twice

Tags: macos, keyboard, automator, services

Following [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2622/change-search-google-in-safari-to-use-firefox/2625#2625) I have created a custom service that executes a shell script that looks like this:

```
open -a FireFox "http://dict.cc/$1"
```

It works fine when I click. Then I defined a custom shortcut for it, (<kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd>), and when I use that, the script seems to get executed twice (two tabs open, both showing the desired page). How can I fix that?

**Edit**: This only seems to happen when I invoce the service using the shortcut from within FireFox.

**Edit 2**: This gets weirder and weirder. I now created a second script for looking up stuff in Google, and bound it to the hotkey <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>. Now when I press that, it actually opens *both* my custom services. I have no idea why this happens.

Also, I removed both the hotkeys temporarily to check if they were used, but nothing happened when I pressed them.

Comment: I wonder if somehow an extension or something in firefox already is using the cmd-shift-L shortcut?

Comment: I checked, and it does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Strange… maybe trying to rebuild your services menu (and then restarting) will help? See the top answer here:

https://superuser.com/questions/43700/snow-leopard-services-menu-says-its-building

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a direct answer to your question, why don't you try something like [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) which allows you to setup custom web queries which are a keyboard shortcut away.

[image: Custom Search Pane]